# send an hyphened/double-hyphened argument to getopts

Tags: linux, bash, shell, getopts

I'm using getopts to get optional arguments in a shell script, and then I use them to run another script.
one of the arguments I'd like to send to the other program is an optional argument (e.g --conf).

but when I'm sending it to getopts i get these error messages:

```
service_wrapper.sh: illegal option -- -
service_wrapper.sh: illegal option -- c
service_wrapper.sh: illegal option -- o
service_wrapper.sh: illegal option -- n
service_wrapper.sh: illegal option -- f
```

is there any way I can send this argument to getopts?

this is the code parsing the options:

```
while getopts 'p:o' OPTION
    do
        case ${OPTION} in
            o) CONF=$OPTARG;;
            p) PLATFORM=$OPTARG;;
        esac
    done
```

this is an example of the line I'm trying to run:

```
./service_wrapper.sh config -p platform -o '--full-config-data {"json_key1":"json_val1","json_key2":"json_val2"}'
```

*EDIT*:

as suggested in the comments I've printed the bash version and the args this is the output:

```
############################
BASH:4.2.46(2)-release
arg: config
arg: -p
arg: platform
arg: -o
arg: --full-config-data {"json_key1":"json_val1","json_key2":"json_val2"}
############################
```

Comment: There is something odd: You execute `service_wrapper.sh`, but the error message comes from a different scirpt (`algobot_services_wrapper.sh`).  There must be something you are hiding from us. I also suggest that, just for debugging, you do a `echo BASH:$BASH_VERSION; for a in "$@"; do echo arg: "$a"; done` and post what you get from this in your question.

Comment: I'm not hiding anything, and everything that's relevant is in the question description.
It was an example with the file name, such as many other questions here, but note's taken, I'll modify filename in error for clarity

Comment: You didn't post the debug output I asked you to include. Only the BASH version, but the arguments are missing.

Comment: @user1934428 my bad, added it now.

Comment: This output was really printed **before** the invocation to `getopts`? getopts complains about the string `config`, which you pass as the first parameter, so I would have expected to see this word at the first position. Perhaps you sould also post the complete code before you start invoking `getopts`.

Comment: @user1934428 i printed now the output if i echo at the start of the code. the former output were after a shift (taken the "config" param as local variable and shifted)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230361/discussion-between-daniel-and-user1934428).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!
After printing the args as @user1934428 suggested,
I've figured out that the last argument is available to the script but not to getopts.

I've tried to understand why and it hit me, a colon is missing after the 'o'!

Instead of `while getopts 'p:o' OPTION`
it should be `while getopts 'p:o:' OPTION`

as noted in [getopts man page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-0210/6m6nb7mao/index.html):

> ***if a letter is followed by a colon, the option is expected to have an argument, or group of arguments, which must be separated from it by white space.***

**Note:** with the information above I fixed the issue and getopts got the last argument, though it parsed it by spaces, even though it was quoted.
It because i sent arguments to main function like this `main $@` when i shouldv'e quoted it like this `main "$@"`.